# Redirect one directory to another path in Linux

Tags: linux, command, home-directory

For one user(say User1) , it has default home directory as /home/User1 . When we give command just **cd**
, it goes to this home directory. But we have another directory called /proj/User1 , which should be the expected directory it should go with just cd command instead of /home/User1.

I suppose , modifying cd command is not good way. Is there any other like softlinking , to go to dir2 whenever we cd to dir1? Please help.

Comment: Perhaps you just want to do `HOME=/proj/User1`, or play around with you CDPATH.

Answer (score 0):

This is the original link where i got the information.
https://superuser.com/questions/167221/can-i-add-a-shortcut-to-replace-a-path-in-linux

Using **Aliases**

```bash
alias somedir='cd /home/john/www/something/'
```

Then you can type "somedir" to go to that directory. Add these to your .bashrc.

Answer (score 0):

Using aliases you can accomplish what you want. You can set them in bashrc. This way, the change will be kept after you reboot your computer.

```bash
echo 'alias cdx="cd /proj/User1"' >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
cdx
```